# Exe's disapear right after compilation

Tags: mingw

When I try to compile a file through the command-line, the executable disappears right after the compilation. This didn't happen before. When I tried to compile through an IDE (CodeBlocks) it did not disappear, and I could open it normally, but this lasted for some days until the same thing happened also with the IDE. I am using MinGW on win7. Anyone can figure out what is going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: Show the command you're using to compile as well as the output from the compile/link steps.  Also, you might want to check any AV that you have installed to make sure it's not moving your programs to quarantine or otherwise deleting them thinking they might be malware.

Comment: You are right, some AV update blocked it. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,   the problem ended up being that I needed to add `c:\mingw\bin` to the system path.   after you add the path, you will need to close and re-open your command line to be able to use the compiler....